# How can we use an Entry to set Time on Timer? (Python, tkinter)

Tags: python

I started coding just a few days ago, so I hope you can help me :)
I'm trying to connect an entry with my timer. So user can choose which time they want to set. They can set the value in minutes. I already got it to get the value of the entry in my timer, but the timer won't start. I'm using tkinter to code this.

So if the user enters e.g. "3" my timer will display "03:00" but time won't start running. The console is printing no errors either. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import math

window = Tk()
window.title("u'Clock")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50, bg="#1a1c20", highlightthickness=0)

timer = None

def start_timer():
    count_down(0)


def get_time():
    time = input_time_do.get()
    int_time = int(time)
    return int_time


def count_down(count):
    count = get_time()
    count_min = count
    count_sec = count*60 % 60
    if count_min < 10:
        count_min = f"0{count_min}"
    if count_sec < 10:
        count_sec = f"0{count_sec}"

    canvas.itemconfig(timer_text, text=f"{count_min}:{count_sec}")
    if count > 0:
        global timer
    window.after(1000, count_down, count - 1)


input_time_do = Entry(width="20", background="DarkSeaGreen")
input_time_do.insert(END, string="Set Workout Time")

input_time_do.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=10, pady=10)

start_button = Button(text="START", command=start_timer)
start_button.grid(column=1, row=6, padx=10, pady=10)

canvas = Canvas(width=400, height=266, bg="#fbf7f0", highlightthickness=0)
gym_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("gym1.jpg"))  # PIL solution
canvas.create_image(200, 133, image=gym_img)
timer_text = canvas.create_text(200, 135, text="00:00", fill="#fbf7f0", font= 
("Roboto", 30))
canvas.grid(column=1, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: In your current code, you are passing the argument `count`, but the first thing you do is overwrite it with the `get_time()` value again.  So it reloads the original value.  I think if your `start_timer` function calls `count_down` with the value of the time field, and you remove that `get_time` call from inside the count down function, you might have something that works.

Comment: You're always setting the time to the same time. Just after you get rid of `count = get_time()` you will realize it starts counting.

Comment: @CoolCloud Isn't that basically what I said in my comment?

Comment: @RufusVS Sure, I just gave TD;DR